# Convert ArrayList<JsonArray> to float[][] in Java

Tags: android, gson

What is best and fastest way to convert an `ArrayList<JsonArray>` to `float[][]` using Gson?

The `ArrayList <JsonArray>` is a 2D array of long with this sample format:

```
[ [ -0.0028871582, -0.0017856462, 0.0078000603, 0.003144495, 0.0042561297, -0.026877755, 0.019066211, 0.050337251, -0.00062063418],
 [ -0.6545645087, 0.7474752828, 1.8797838739, 0.287287200, 0.0007858753, -0.742472785, 0.019066211, 0.050337251, -0.00062063418],
... ]
```

People say I should scan each item with two go and do the conversion but do not know if there is a more automated means for this.

Comment: What has `Gson.fromJson` given you?

Comment: Java's `long` only represents whole numbers, no decimals. All items in your sample list would be cut off after the decimal point. Are you sure this fulfills your requirements?

Comment: Gson.fromJson = ArrayList<JsonArray>

Comment: Gson should be able to take a TypeToken that represents a `float[][]`, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @njzk2 mentioned `fromJson` takes a second parameter describing your data. It can be a [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) or a [`Type`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html).

---

#### `Class` example

```
String json = "[\n" +
        "    [ -0.0028871582, -0.0017856462, 0.0078000603 ],\n" +
        "    [ -0.6545645087, 0.7474752828, 1.8797838739 ]\n" +
        "]\n";

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
float[][] r = gson.fromJson(json, float[][].class);
for (float[] a: r) {
    for (float f : a) {
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

---

#### `Type` example

```
Type myType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<Float>>>() {}.getType();
List<List<Float>> r = gson.fromJson(json, myType);
for (List<Float> a: r) {
    for (Float f: a) {
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```