# How to convert ArrayList<JsonArray> in byte array in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, arrays

What is the best way to convert an `ArrayList<JsonArray>` to byte[] in Java?

I tried `myJsonArrayList.toString().getBytes()` but to check the values (return `ArrayList<JsonArray>`) is being divergent.

The values contained in `JsonArray` are `float[]`.

Comment: Why not just iterate over the list and add them to a freshly constructed byte[] array? This is a very simple solution. If you're looking for a library then this question is not appropriate for StackOverflow

Comment: I assume you're trying to convert the `float` arrays in `JsonArray`s to `byte` arrays.

Comment: VTR2015, can you tell us just how closely related this question is to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887814/convert-arraylistjsonarray-to-float-in-java)?

Comment: First, I do not know why I became negative!!! The other post was answered correctly and doubt was another! End over! I focused on another post with another doubt one of Convert ArrayList<JsonArray> to byte array 1d !!!
I see a response with byte array 2d if I were to follow the negativity rule you would have negated this wrong answer!
I created this new post because I believe that the question has no influence with the above, since the answer to that does not work for this question!

Answer (score 0):

*Before reading this, please keep in mind that I assume the asker is trying to convert the `float[]`s of `JsonArray`s to `byte[]`s.*

**Step 1:** Create an `ArrayList` of `byte` arrays. Note that `byte[]` is a legitimate type, so you don't need to use an array of wrapper `java.lang.Byte`s.

```
ArrayList<byte[]> byteArrays = new ArrayList<>();
```

**Step 2:** Enter a `for`each loop that iterates over the `ArrayList<JsonArray>` (let's say your `ArrayList<JsonArray>` is called `jsonArrays`).

```
for (JsonArray jsonArray : jsonArrays) { // P.S This is the outer loop
```

**Step 3:** In the loop, do the following things which I explained with comments:

```
float[] floats = jsonArray.getFloats(); // Get the float[] located in jsonArray
byte[] bytes = new byte[floats.length]; // Create a byte[] that has the exact same length with the above float[]
for (int index = 0; index < bytes.length; index++)
    bytes[index] = (byte) floats[index]; // Cast the float values to byte values
byteArrays.add(bytes); // Put the byte array to byteArrays
} // This is where the outer loop ends
```

**Step 4:** Convert `byteArrays` into a `byte[][]`, or in other words, an array of `byte` arrays.

```
byte[][] values = byteArrays.toArray();
```

Aaaaaaaand it's done!

Now let's put it all together:

```
ArrayList<byte[]> byteArrays = new ArrayList<>();
for (JsonArray jsonArray : jsonArrays) {
    float[] floats = jsonArray.getFloats();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[floats.length];
    for (int index = 0; index < bytes.length; index++)
        bytes[index] = (byte) floats[index];
    byteArrays.add(bytes);
}
byte[][] values = byteArrays.toArray();
```